# How to use message queue with Windows phone 8 app?

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-8, rabbitmq

I have a windows phone 8 application, which communicates with WCF service using basicHttpBinding. The service is hosted on IIS7 (and not using windows azure)

As the service may go down for any reason, I am exploring the use of message queues to increase the reliability of the system.

I have looked at NetMsmqBinding provided in WCF - but it looks like this binding is not supported by WP8 client.
I am also looking at using RabbitMQ, but cannot find any working example with WP8 client using WCF.

Please can anyone suggest what is the best way forward? Any sample code (or links) will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First off, netMsmqBinding cannot be used across the internet. This is because it uses MSMQ which is not exposed over http.

When you're making calls to a resource across the internet, unreliability is something you need to factor into your application. Because of the [number of possible problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24361780/569662) you can encounter, it's generally not a case of if, but when, there is a failure and it's [how your application deals with this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pedram/archive/2008/01/25/wcf-error-handling-and-some-best-practices.aspx) which is important.

Even so, there are things you can do to minimize the reliability issues you experience, one of which does involve queuing.

Where queuing can be useful is taking large, complex, and long running processes offline. Because calls to such processes implemented synchronously often time out, you can gain a lot of reliability by making the actual processing call asynchronous.

As an example, it would be fairly common to have the web server invoke some offline process via message queuing and return to the client that their request is being processed. Because doing this is inexpensive calls are far less likely to fail. Your problem then becomes one of how to [return the response to the client](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24732576/569662) once the offline processing has been done.

Comment: Thanks - actually I am already using asynchronous operation on the client. So if the client sends the data to the service and it fails, client will get an error message and it can resend the data once the service is back. So there is no loss of data. However I am exploring whether I can avoid relying on the user to resend the data if it fails - or can I use message queues to take this burden off the user.

Comment: Hi @gunnerz if you require a queued binding not sure I can help you. But it seems like you're doing all the right things. I guess you could automate the retries so that the user doesn't need to physically resend.